# Elastic Search : {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index using NLog in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, nlog

This error comes when I searched the index in elastic search by http://localhost:9200/myservicename

following is my n.config file

```
    <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="ElasticSearch"
    flushTimeout="5000"/>
    <target name="elastic" xsi:type="ElasticSearch" index="myservicename"
            uri="http://localhost:9200"
            requireAuth="true"
     username="elastic"
     password="dd+A0Y=mmE1RgmIDoeHh"
            layout ="API:MyServiceName|${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" >
    </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="elastic" />
</rules>
```

****

Please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: Check if you have this index with `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices/`.

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring because the index is not created / available in Elasticsearch. Please check this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html).

You can create index using below curl command:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/myservicename?pretty"
```

You can used below command to check if index is exist or not:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/myservicename?pretty"
```

You can also do same using Postman client and execute same API for creating index.

Comment: After using this curl command, index is created but no logs is shown in kibana. Now what will I do?

Comment: @SANJANABAJPAI it will be great if you can raise seperate question for this and please add more details like what configiuration you have done, how you validate data is not indexing, if there is any error in elastic log file or your application log file etc.